# Recorrer JSONObject en Java

Tags: java, android, json, jsonobject

Tengo un problema recorriendo el JsonObjet que tengo.

El Json es algo así:

```
   {
  "type": "REGISTRO",
  "0": {
    "ID": "7",
    "nombre": "prueba1",
    "date": "2020-05-20",
    "time": "16:39:53",
    "mail": "correo@correo.es"
  },
  "1": {
    "ID": "8",
    "nombre": "prueba2",
    "date": "2020-05-20",
    "time": "19:10:41",
    "mail": "correo2@correo.es"
  }
}
```

Pues bien, no se cómo extraer lo de dentro del 0 y cambiar al 1.

Tengo hecho esto, pero da error:

```
Iterator<String> keys = response.keys();



while(keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    if (response.get(key) instanceof JSONObject && !"type".equals(response.get(key))){
                        // do something with jsonObject here
                        Log.d("response","dentro array");
                        Iterator<String> values = ((JSONObject) response.get(key)).keys();
                        while (values.hasNext()){
                            String value_key = keys.next();
                            if(((JSONObject) response.get(key)).has("ID")){
                                Log.d("response", response.getString("ID"));
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, estoy intentando entender lo mejor posible el tema de los JSON.

¡Gracias!

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta ni por qué usas un iterador. Cuando trabajas con JSON es importante que sepas entender su estructura. Si quieres lo que hay en la clave `0`, accede directamente a ella. La estructura indica que dentro de esa clave hay un `JSONObject`, entonces obtenlo y luego obtienes cada dato dentro de él y lo mismo para el `1`. Si está en tus manos, sería más simple crear un `JSONArray` y dentro de él los `JSONObject` así los recorrerlas con un bucle simplemente sin tanto lío. Sea como sea no se entiende con claridad lo que quieres hacer realmente.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Lo que preguntaba era cómo extraer el contenido de 0 y 1, pero de forma automatizada, con un bucle para que no dependiera de cuantos valores hubiera. No se si me explico :S

Comment: Es lo que te he dicho al final de mi comentario, lo pongo de nuevo aquí: *Si está en tus manos, sería más simple crear un `JSONArray` y dentro de él los `JSONObject` así los recorrerías con un bucle simplemente sin tanto lío...* Tal y como lo tienes ahora es imposible, tendrías que modificar el JSON, de modo que quedase así...:

Comment: `{
   "type":"REGISTRO",
   "laClave":[
      {
         "ID":"7",
         "nombre":"prueba1",
         "date":"2020-05-20",
         "time":"16:39:53",
         "mail":"correo@correo.es"
      },
      {
         "ID":"8",
         "nombre":"prueba2",
         "date":"2020-05-20",
         "time":"19:10:41",
         "mail":"correo2@correo.es"
      }
   ]
}` ahí vas a tener en `laClave`, que se llamaría de otro modo claro está, un array con todos los objetos JSON que existan, y podrás leerlos todos, sea 1, sean 100, sean 7, dentro de un bucle.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! He estado trasteando un poco y he conseguido obtenerlo también así (saltando el type) `JSONArray names = response.names();
                        for (int i = 1; i < response.length(); i++){
                            Object aux = response.get(names.getString(i));
                            Log.d("response",aux.toString());
                        }`

Comment: mmmm no sé, lo más simple es que ordenes tu JSON de forma que  lo puedas leer con las mayor facilidad posible. Si el JSON lo organizas como en el ejemplo, podrías acceder a un objeto `JSONArray` mediante algo como `JSONArray mData = response.getJSONArray("laClave");` y luego recorrer con un bucle `mData` y leer los objetos que hay dentro para mostrar cada dato.

Comment: Vale ¡Muchas gracias! Lo haré

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los comentarios, la mejor solución sería cambiar el JSON para que sea de esta manera:

`{
  "type": "RECORD",
  "Results": [{
    "ID": "7",
    "nombreRecord": "alergia",
    "date": "2020-05-21",
    "time": "16:39:53",
    "mail": "naza@correo.es"
  }, {
    "ID": "8",
    "nombreRecord": "Cabeza",
    "date": "2020-05-21",
    "time": "19:10:41",
    "mail": "naza@correo.es"
  }]
}`

Una vez tenemos eso, para extraer los datos:

```
JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("Results");
for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
    JSONObject aux = results.getJSONObject(i);
    Log.d("response","ID" + aux.get("ID"));
}
```